Compute the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} n\int_{-1}^{1} x(1-x^2)^{n-1}g(x)dx$
Let $g$ be a bounded real-valued function on $[-1,1]$, which is continuous at all points other than $x=0$ and satisfies $g(0) = 1$, $\lim_{x\to 0^+} g(x) = 2$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-}g(x)=3$. Compute
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\int_{-1}^{1} x(1-x^2)^{n-1} g(x)dx.$$
I have tried to first break the interval into three parts: $[-1,-\delta]$, $[-\delta, \delta]$, $[\delta,1]$, $\forall |x-0|\leq \delta$, and then I know the integral is $0$ when $x\notin [-\delta,\delta]$, but I don't know how to compute the integral for this part. Could you give me some hint for this? I am not sure if applying the Heine-Cantor Theorem to show uniform continuity would help.

Two side-remarks. 1) $g(0)=1$ is irrelevant. 2) Your problem easily reduces to $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\int_0^1x(1-x^2)^{n-1}h(x)dx$$ where $h$ is bounded and $\lim_0h=5$.

Observe that $$\int\limits_{-1}^1nx(1-x^2)^{n-1}g(x),dx =\int\limits_0^1nx(1-x^2)^{n-1}f(x),dx$$ where $f(x)={1\over 2}[g(x)+g(-x)]$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)={5\over 2}.$ In this way you can  slightly simplify the problem.

Thank you so much for your hint! That is pretty insightful point for me!

On any interval $[-1,-\delta]\cup[\delta, 1]$ with $0<\delta<1$, we have that $nx(1-x^2)^{n-1}\to0$ uniformly. This guarantees that
$$
\int_{-1}^{-\delta} nx(1-x^2)^{n-1}g(x )\,dx+
\int_{\delta}^1 nx(1-x^2)^{n-1}g(x )\,dx \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.
$$
Given $\def\e{\varepsilon}\e>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $2-\e\leq g(x)\leq2+\e$ for $x\in[0,\delta]$. Then
\begin{align}
(2-\e)\int_{0}^{\delta} nx(1-x^2)^{n-1}\,dx&\leq\int_{0}^{\delta} nx(1-x^2)^{n-1}g(x )\,dx\\[0.2cm]&\leq(2+\e)\int_{0}^{\delta} nx(1-x^2)^{n-1}\,dx.
\end{align}
Noting that
$$
\int_{0}^{\delta} nx(1-x^2)^{n-1}\,dx=-\frac12\,(1-x^2)^n\bigg|_0^\delta=\frac12\,[1-(1-\delta^2)^n]\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac12,
$$
We get
$$
\frac{2-\e}2\leq\int_{0}^{\delta} nx(1-x^2)^{n-1}g(x )\,dx\leq\frac{2+\e}2.
$$
Repeating the process with $3-\e\leq g(x)\leq3+\e$ on $[-\delta,0]$,
$$
\frac{3-\e}2\leq\int_{-\delta}^0 nx(1-x^2)^{n-1}g(x )\,dx\leq\frac{3+\e}2.
$$
Adding the inequalities and taking limit, we get
$$
\frac{5-\e}2\leq\limsup_{n\to\infty}\int_{-1}^1nx(1-x^2)^{n-1}g(x )\,dx\leq\frac{5+\e}2.
$$
The same inequalities can be obtained with liminf  and, as $\e$ was arbitrary, the limit exists and
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-1}^1nx(1-x^2)^{n-1}g(x )\,dx=\frac{5}2. 
$$

Thank you so much for your insightful hint and detailed proof! I think this perfectly figured my confusion out!

Glad I could help!

Hi Martin, I have one more question: why do we need a limsup & liminf here instead of just take the limit of the integral? Thank you so much!

Because in principle you don't know that the limit exists. "Taking limit" of something you don't know if the limit exists is not really correct. Particularly here, $\varepsilon$  is fixed and we are moving $n$, so the only things we are sure exist are the limsup and liminf. After we show these are equal, we conclude that the limit exists.

Thank you so much for your further clarification! That makes more sense for me!

Split the integral into two parts
$$I= \lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_{-1}^0x(1-x^2)^{n-1}g(x)dx + \lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1x(1-x^2)^{n-1}g(x)dx$$
then use the substitution $u=(1-x^2)^n$ on both pieces separately
$$I = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1g\left(-\sqrt{1-u^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)du+\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1g\left(\sqrt{1-u^{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)du$$
$$\longrightarrow \int_0^1\frac{g(0^-)+g(0^+)}{2}du = \frac{5}{2}$$
by dominated convergence.

Thank you so much for your help! I think this method perfectly simplify the problem and deliver it to a understandable sense.
